# Creating an audio panel in Linux for Creative X-fi

Tags: linux, audio

Creative released Linux drivers for the X-FI which is nice but the card sounds no better than typical onboard sound in Linux. "Mixers" in Linux tend to be nothing more than volume adjustment. Equalizers are app-based and pretty bad as well.

In Windows, it sounds amazing.

The difference is the audio control panel which has settings for Dolby, Crystalizer, Mode(Entertainment, Game, creation), etc.

Before I spend too much time digging into the driver, does anyone know if the Linux driver is complete enough to write a similar control panel?